# Exercise styles in answers.sty

Tags: theorems

With the answers package I am trying to change the font of the exercise from italic to non-italic. I am looking for a solution that does not require me to add something to each and every exercise.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{ex}{}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[1.1.1ans]

\section*{1.1.1 Check Your Understanding}
\begin{ex}
Evaluate 1+1
\begin{sol}
2
\end{sol}
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
What are the x-intercepts of f(x)?
\begin{sol}
0
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\subsection*{Challenge}
\begin{ex}
What is the square root of -1?
\begin{sol}
$i$
\end{sol}
\end{ex}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\subsection*{Answers}
\input{1.1.1ans}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the default definition of the environment theorem.

[image: a]

You will get the default output using   `\newcommand{\theorStyle}{\itshape}` Try `\large` or `\bfseries` to see how it works.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{ex}{}

% *************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\theorStyle}{\normalfont}% choose the style<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\def\@begintheorem#1#2{\trivlist%
    \item[\hskip \labelsep{\bfseries #1\ #2}]\theorStyle}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \Opensolutionfile{ans}[1.1.1ans]
    
    \section*{1.1.1 Check Your Understanding}
    \begin{ex}
        Evaluate 1+1
        \begin{sol}
            2
        \end{sol}
    \end{ex}
    \begin{ex}
        What are the x-intercepts of f(x)?
        \begin{sol}
            0
        \end{sol}
    \end{ex}
    
    \subsection*{Challenge}
    \begin{ex}
        What is the square root of -1?
        \begin{sol}
            $i$
        \end{sol}
    \end{ex}
    
    \Closesolutionfile{ans}
    \subsection*{Answers}
    \input{1.1.1ans}
    
\end{document}
```